# Twitter, Dukt OAuth, and Placid error

Tags: plugin-duktoauth

Trying to get Placid working but I can't get Twitter to Connect. The keys are all set correctly, but when I click 'Connect', I get this error:

```
Craft\OauthService and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "encodeToken".
```

On line 266 of /home/rizen/sites/rizencreative.com/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php(266)

```
throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','{class} and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "{name}".',
    array('{class}'=>get_class($this), '{name}'=>$name)));
```

Answer (score 3):

@crawf was right with his answer, but I recently saw the preview release for Craft 3, so Placid 2 is going to wait and be written for that.

So I thought I should fix the current version of Placid to work with the latest version of OAuth (currently `0.9.71`) and as a brucie bonus you can now connect to more than just the twitter api :)

[You can get the latest version (`1.3.0`) on github](https://github.com/alecritson/Placid) and any issues just give us a shout on the repo (or here, whichever you feel most relevant)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the 0.9.60 version of OAuth? There are some issues with Placid and the latest OAuth version, which will be fixed in Placid 2.

Comment: Is there a release date on that update? Stuck with the same problem here.

Comment: No, I'm sure Alec is working on it. I can confirm that Placid 1.2.5 works with OAuth 0.9.60. Just download the older OAuth plugin from [Dukt](https://github.com/dukt/craft-oauth/releases/tag/0.9.60) and use that for now. Works great!

Comment: The latest version has been pushed to github, which should see this error fixed, see my answer above